# How can I use Picture in Picture mode on Android versions below Oreo?

Tags: java, android, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I'm developing an app that has the PiP mode. According to the documentation is available only from the Oreo version. Is there any other way (official or unofficial) to use PiP in lower versions than Oreo?

Comment: You can't unless you roll your own (difficult). At least in my experience.